# How long between flair updates?

Tags: support

I have over 200 in reputation in both Stack Overflow and here (reached +200 yesterday or so).

How long is it between flair updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flair generally updates every 24 hours or so; it is heavily cached, so patience is advised.